# $X$ a normed space. $(x_n) \subset X$ s.t. $|f(x_n)| < M_f$ for all $n$ and $\forall f \in X^{\ast}$ then there is $C$ s.t. $\|x_n\| \le C$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ a normed vector space and $(x_n) \subset X$ such that  $|f(x_n)| < M_f$ for all $n$ and $\forall f \in X^{\ast}$, where $M_f$ is a constant depending on $f.$ (Here we are assuming that if $f \in X^{\ast}$ then $f$ is continuous). Then there is $C>0$ s.t. $\|x_n\| \le C~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

It seems natural how to proceed. I can take the sup on the set $X^{\ast}$ considering only $f$ such that $\|f\| = 1$. Then we have
$$\|x_n\| \le \sup_{\{f \in X^{\ast}: \|f\| = 1\}}M_f.$$

The problem is, how can I be sure that $\|x_n\| \le \sup_{\{f \in X^{\ast}: \|f\| = 1\}}M_f < \infty?$

Thanks

Comment: what is $M_f$? Just some constant?

Comment: sorry! Yes, it is a constant that depends on $f$.

Comment: The Banach-Steinhaus theorem may prove useful in this situation.

Comment: thank you! @minimalrho, I dindnt see this theorem yet. This relief's me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the [Banach-Steinhaus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) applied to the dual space $X^*$ which is always a Banach space, even if $X$ is only a normed space.

For $x \in X$ let $\hat x \in X^{**} = (X^*)^*$ be defined via $\hat x(f) = f(x)$ for all $f \in X^*$. Then, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f \in X^*$ we have
$$
|\hat{x_n}(f)| = |f(x_n)| \leq M_f,
$$
i.e. the family of operators $(\hat{x_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is pointwise bounded.

Banach-Steinhaus gives you that the family is uniformly bounded, i.e. there exists some $C > 0$ such that
$$
\|\hat{x_n}\| \leq C,
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

But $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of its Bi-dual, i.e. $\|\hat{x_n}\| = \|x_n\|$.